How to access the data of an unencrypted Ubuntu installation on a internal hard drive with a single user password protected session?
Let's say that I have an unecrypted Ubuntu installation on an internal hard drive of a computer. There I am the only user using this computer with one username and a corresponding password. Is it possible to access the data of the hard disk and if yes how?

Your details are somewhat confusing, at least to me. You mention an unencrypted Ubuntu installation but have tagged encryption..  What is encrypted, and what exactly is unencrypted?  If the installed system you're wanting to use is unencrypted, I'd not expect issues in trying to access the data/installation from a live system.  Do you know what encryption is used?  as you tagged LUKS, but weren't specific as to LUKS1, LUKS2, or if the encryption is something else.  FYI Ubuntu's default encryption has changed over time, so providing release details lets us better understand too

"Let's say that..." do you have an actual issue to resolve or is your question just seeking an opinion based one?

@guiverc thank you for your comments. My system is not encrypted (and not un-encrypted). I removed the tag. You mean then that in that case I should be able to access file from a live session e.g. flash USB drive with iso ubuntu on it?

@graham. Thank you for your comment. I have no issue: I am considering encrypting my file system and want to know what are the consequences of not doing it

Yes, whilst still provided no specifics (ie. no product/release details of Ubuntu, nor file-system data, as differences can occur, eg. ext4, btrfs, xfs, zfs etc..) but you should be able to access data from a live system (eg. Ubuntu Desktop and using the Try mode) if correct command(s) or GUI tools are used..  Complexity can vary on file-system involved though as you didn't provide details.

This question is similar to: Question on accessing salvaged Ubuntu boot drive. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If the system is properly configured, then there are two possibilites.

Your data is already accessible. It was mounted with the rest of the system at startup. Your data is on a partition listed in /etc/fstab for automounting.

Your data is not already aceessible. Typically, this means a different partition was not mounted at startup. Use the mount command to mount the partition to your filesystem. See man mount for usage.


